# Add a code into app.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm new to Javascript. I'm building an app using Ionic. 
First I created app using `ionic start MyAPPOne tabs`
Then I installed `Cordova Text-to-Speech`Plugin 
This is my `app.js`

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

I want to add this code into my `app.js`.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])


.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    speechText: ''
  };
  $scope.recognizedText = '';

  $scope.speakText = function() {
    TTS.speak({
           text: $scope.data.speechText,
           locale: 'en-GB',
           rate: 1.5
       }, function () {
           // Do Something after success
       }, function (reason) {
           // Handle the error case
       });
  };

  $scope.record = function() {
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        if (event.results.length > 0) {
            $scope.recognizedText = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            $scope.$apply()
        }
    };
    recognition.start();
  };
});
```

So how can I do it? I tried to merge this by pasted this code in `app.js` but when I checked this via `ionic serve` the app didn't show tabs. How can I merge this?

Comment: cordova plugins don't work on browsers, try with emulator or device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
```

with

```
angular.module('starter.controllers')
```